# C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Can you explain me what is the meaning of this regular expression. What would be the string which matches to this expression.

```
Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
```

what is @ symbol?? Thanks in advance.

> Please provide full explaination. What
>   would be the string which matches to
>   this expression.

Comment: @ means a verbatim string. That means that escape sequences don't work, which is useful with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` symbol designates a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx):

> A verbatim string literal consists of
>   an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more
>   characters, and a closing double-quote
>   character. A simple example is
>   @"hello". In a verbatim string
>   literal, the characters between the
>   delimiters are interpreted verbatim,
>   the only exception being a
>   quote-escape-sequence. In particular,
>   simple escape sequences and
>   hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in
>   verbatim string literals. A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple
>   lines.

As for the regular expression it breaks down like this:

> `/Type` **match this string exactly**
>   `\s*` **match any whitespace character zero or more times**
>   `/Page` **match this string exactly**
>   `[^s]` **match any character that isn't "s"**

Comment: Expresso as well as other tools can help learn what a regular expression means. 

http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 2):

`@` says that the string literal is verbatim.

The regex matches:

`/Type` followed by zero or more whitespaces, followed by `/Page` and a character that is not `s`

It will match strings like `/Type/Pagex`, `/Type     /Page3`, `/Type /Page?`

Answer (score 1):

@ starts a c# verbatim string, in which the compiler doesn't process escape sequences, making writing expressions with lots of \ characters easier.

both of the following match

```
/Type /Page4
/Type             /Pagex
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression matches any string containing the following:

- A "/" character
- The word "Type" (case sensitive)
- Optionally, some whitespace
- Another "/"
- The word "Page" (case sensitive)
- Any character that isn't an "s"

Examples would be "/Type /Paged" or "/Type/Pager".

If you want to match either "Page" or "Pages" at the end, you probably want this instead:

Regex(@"/Type\s*/Pages?");

Here is a good [online C# regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, it matches: **/Type{optional space}/Page{not an 's'}**